# Trigger after insert and joining tables to update

Tags: sql, oracle

I got 3 tables:

```
BOOK(bookid primary, nbloans)
COPIES(copyid primary,bookid)
BORROW(bid primary,copyid)
```

I want to create a trigger after insert on borrow that increments BOOK.nbloans.
I tried the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger4
AFTER INSERT ON BORROW
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN 
   UPDATE BOOK
   SET NBLOANS = NBLOANS + 1
   WHERE BORROW.COPYID=COPIES.COPYID AND  COPIES.BOOKID=BOOK.BOOKID;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is, but a trigger in SQL usually refers to `:new` and/or `:old`.  So I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger4
AFTER INSERT ON BORROW
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN 
   UPDATE BOOK B
       SET NBLOANS = NBLOANS + 1
      WHERE B.BOOKID = (SELECT C.BOOKID
                        FROM COPIES C
                        WHERE C.COPYID = :NEW.COPYID
                       );
END;
```

Comment: borrow does not have a book id

Comment: @ElioRahy . . . I updated the answer to lookup the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MERGE` statement as follows:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger4
> AFTER INSERT ON BORROW
> FOR EACH ROW   
> BEGIN 
>    MERGE INTO BOOKS B
>    USING (SELECT copyid,bookid FROM COPIES WHERE copyid = :NEW.copyid ) C
>    ON (B.BOOKID = C.bookid)
>    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET B.nbloans = nbloans + 1;
> END;
> ```

Cheers!!